# Variety of Probabilistic Independence

Tags: geometry, probability-theory, manifolds, independence, affine-varieties

We may consider a probability space on $n$ outcomes as a point in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by assigning outcomes to standard basis vectors, and picking a point with its coordinate on each basis vector equal to the probability of the corresponding outcomes. The point then belongs to the probability simplex: $\Delta^n$, which is a regular $n$-simplex given as the convex hull of the standard basis vectors. This gives us a new geometric representation of independence. Let's consider all probability spaces where our outcomes are $(a,b,c...)$ for $1\leq a\leq A$, $1\leq b\leq B$ and so on, with the coordinates of our outcomes mutually independent. This set is the intersection of $\Delta^{ABC...}$ with an affine variety $V$ in $\mathbb{C}^{ABC...+1}$. $V$ is the zero set of equations $\
[p(a_0,b_1,c_1,...)+p(a_1,b_1,c_1,...)...]p(a_0,b_0,c_0,...)-[p(a_0,b_0,c_0,...)+p(a_1,b_0,c_0,...)...]p(a_0,b_1,c_1,...)$, where $p(\cdot)$ denotes probability. What can we say about $V$? Its dimension is obvious. Is it connected? Does it have singular points? Does it have a nice parametrization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$V$ is the affine cone over a [Segre variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segre_embedding). The Segre variety itself is isomorphic to a product of projective spaces (more or less by definition) so in particular is connected and smooth.

This sort of connection between probability and algebraic geometry goes under the name [algebraic statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_statistics). You can check out, for example, *[Lectures on Algebraic Statistics](https://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/owl.pdf)* by Drton, Sturmfels, and Sullivant.